# When should Hyperledger fabric be used in place of regular databases?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, distributed

It's my understanding that everything Hyperledger fabric offers can be done on regular database software.

For example, "smart contracts" are analogous to stored procedures. Also, there are some existing pieces of "distributed database" software that appear to be equivalent to what fabric can do. For example, the [X-Road](https://e-estonia.com/solutions/interoperability-services/x-road/) project from e-Estonia.

EDIT: I've been told a better example of a distributed database is Apache CouchDB. How is this "Distributed Ledger" idea different from CouchDB?

When does Hyperledger fabric offer an advantage?

Comment: I think all depends on your backend business system. But still some data can not storage in distributed database since the difference of the distributed runtime system, like the timestamp generate by different peer.

Comment: X-Road is a data exchange layer between service consumers and service providers. X-Road is not a [distributed database](https://www.niis.org/blog/2018/9/3/x-road-myth-busting-part-1) and there's [no blockchain technology in X-Road](https://www.niis.org/blog/2018/4/26/there-is-no-blockchain-technology-in-the-x-road).

Comment: I think main advantage is to eliminate centralized control. But also :
1. Immutability (almost impossible to alter or remove data)
2. Decentralization (different actors don't need to trust each others thanks to consensus)
3. Transparency & history (every user can check the blockchain over time, and it can be made public easily)
4. Security & confidentiality (confidentiality between actors thanks to channels, security thanks to cryptography and the ledger being replicated on each peers interacting into the network).
Main downside is slowness and maybe the setup complexity (for the moment).